# lsblk partuuid not recognized command

Tags: usb, partitioning

I'm trying to find out where the partitions start for my USB using the

```
lsblk -o name,label,partuuid
```

It's giving me an output of:

```
lsblk: unknown column: partuuid
```

I believe "partuuid" is not a permitted command for Ubuntu. Any idea on how i can find this information out?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and `lsblk`?

Comment: Ubuntu is 14.04.1, "lsblk --version" didn't tell me the version of lsblk i am using. I tried sudo apt-get install lsblk but i got "E: Unable to locate package lsblk"

Comment: The `lsblk` in Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't understand partition GUIDs (`partuuid`). It works as you'd expect in 16.04.

Comment: @RodSmith Thanks Rod, didn't know that. I've answered my own question though. It's a a difficult way to get the PARTUUID but it works for Ubuntu 14! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way i found the UUID was by first identifying what partition of the USB i wanted to boot from, i did this by typing

```
lsblk
```

It gave me a dev tree, so outlining SDB1, SDB2 and SDB3. I knewi wanted to boot from SDB2, because this was the root file system.

I wrote a small script, passing /dev/sdb as the variable through it.

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo dd if=/dev/$1 bs=4 skip=110 count=1 | hexdump
```

It gave me the PARTUUID in the wrong endian format, so i just swapped it around. So the UUID for SDB2 is xxxxxxxx-02

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to identify the partition via a "partuuid" (really a GUID), you can get the partition unique GUID via GPT fdisk (`gdisk`, `sgdisk`, or `cgdisk`). If you need it from a script or a one-line command, `sgdisk` is the best bet. You'd do something like this:

```
$ sudo sgdisk -i 2 /dev/sda | grep unique
Partition unique GUID: 4D72D277-2E94-4760-8B38-8A487615E2E3
```

This example gets the partition's unique GUID ("partuuid") from partition 2 (`-i 2` on `/dev/sda` -- that is, `/dev/sda2`. This example pipes the output through `grep` simply to isolate the one line that's relevant -- this particular `sgdisk` command returns seven lines of output with various types of information on the partition.

To match the GUID to a known value, you'd need to loop through all the partitions, doing further processing on the output. This is likely to be awkward compared to something like viewing the contents of `/dev/disk/by-partuuid/`, but depending on the broader goal, it might be helpful or necessary. For instance, if you're trying to collect assorted data on the *partitions* (but *not* the filesystems they contain), `sgdisk` presents more than just the partition's GUID -- as I said, there are seven lines of output from the `-i` option:

```
$ sudo sgdisk -i 2 /dev/sda
Partition GUID code: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 (Linux filesystem)
Partition unique GUID: 4D72D277-2E94-4760-8B38-8A487615E2E3
First sector: 1128448 (at 551.0 MiB)
Last sector: 2664447 (at 1.3 GiB)
Partition size: 1536000 sectors (750.0 MiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'Unused /boot'
```

If you want to show all that summary data, or even just three or four lines of it, then it may be better to use `sgdisk` than to try to piece it together from other sources.

Answer (score 2):

## PARTUUID doesn't work under Ubuntu 14.04

As per comments under OP question Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't support the `PARTUUID` flag.

## PARTUUID works under Ubuntu 16.04 to show your USB drive

As you can see `PARTUUID` works fine on my Ubuntu 16.04 to show the USB Thumb Drive / Flash Drive's UUID:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,PARTUUID,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,MODEL
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL            PARTUUID                             MOUNTPOINT   SIZE MODEL
sdb                                                                                   7.6G USB Flash Disk  
└─sdb1      vfat   LIVE_USB         bb958812-01                          /media/ric   7.6G 
sda                                                                                 931.5G HGST HTS721010A9
├─sda4      ntfs   WINRETOOLS       c8cd5c7e-48fc-4aac-8c57-abcf6819b3ce              450M 
├─sda2                              0e4d96d3-5164-4d2f-9786-5e7b5066034e              128M 
├─sda5      ntfs   Image            b929ccc6-7ceb-4c50-a14c-8e41bf9d401f             11.4G 
├─sda3      ntfs   HGST_Win10       8778bdd3-e557-4f16-8fd6-9d44dcfe0c0a /mnt/d       919G 
└─sda1      vfat   ESP              edde67a5-6d32-425b-8e4e-6343b3e3f6f1              500M 
nvme0n1                                                                               477G Samsung SSD 960 PRO
├─nvme0n1p5 ext4   NVMe_Ubuntu_16.0 f1f35cf5-1b79-4d43-84e3-9b10ea3f9e3c /           44.6G 
├─nvme0n1p3                         6471dce0-3ba5-49b9-bd13-667ad8f72b10               16M 
├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs                    f5872f63-c0c7-4136-b65d-b89becdfc138              450M 
├─nvme0n1p6 swap   Linux Swap       4aeb7d53-7ad5-41b2-99f3-cae583bca6b7 [SWAP]       7.9G 
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs   NVMe_Win10       f354f364-9819-4209-955a-297505eebfd0 /mnt/c     414.9G 
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat                    5a989e57-3bb3-4821-907f-5822bb14a635 /boot/efi     99M 
└─nvme0n1p7 ntfs   Shared_WSL+Linux 1ca41115-5e65-4ade-8825-b9a2807ae51c /mnt/e         9G
```

Comment: See [comments under question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906524/lsblk-partuuid-not-recognized-command#comment1424093_906524): feature wasn't available in 14.04, which OP was using.

Comment: @muru Should I delete my answer and VTC question? Revise my answer?

Comment: up to you. Just pointing out that there was no configuration error, just an older system.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual page (in a terminal type `man lsblk`):

-o, --output list
              Specify which output columns to print.  Use --help to get a list
              of all supported columns.

So `lsblk --help` should give you, among other things, a list of supported colums.

To list partition uuids use the command `blkid`instead of `lsblk`.

I am not at my Ubuntu machine right now to verify it, but please try it anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately partuuid is not in the help list, if i don't know this unique identifier then i can't tell my system to boot from it

Comment: Use `blkid` instead .. I have updated my answer with this

Comment: Thanks Soren A, but that still only lists the UUID for me, output is below:

/dev/sdb2: LABEL="ROOT" UUID="a179b05f-de0e-4f38-adf6-10a6a5aeb3cf" TYPE="ext3"

Comment: @bahjat You asked for partition UUID .. then I don't understand your question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To just see the UUID *and* PARTUUID you can just use `ls`:

- `ls -l /dev/disk/by-partuuid/` to see all partition's partuuid's
- `ls -l /dev/disk/by-partuuid/` to see all partition's uuid's

---

The right label for UUID is just uuid, so replace "partuuid" with "uuid" in your command.

```
lsblk -o name,label,uuid
```

You'll probably need `sudo` to read the UUID too.

---

But really, if you're *trying to find out where the partitions start for my USB* you probably want to use something else, like `fdisk` or `cfdisk` or `parted` or probably best `gparted`.

Comment: unfortunately that only tells me the "UUID" i'm after the "PARTUUID"

Comment: The UUID is a unique id for each filesystem *in each partition*. It's often how partitions are identified for mounting / booting / etc. The PARTUUID is apparently stored in/by the GPT, I'll edit in info on how to view both with `ls`